# Android SDK - ListView, launch different intents based on which row was clicked

Tags: android, listview, sdk, onitemclicklistener

new to android development and im working on getting my iOS app to Android. In my app im using listviews, and that works great. This is what i have so far, and its inside a tabwidget.

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.row_style, ITEMS));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

static final String[] ITEMS = new String[] {
    "Apple", "Google", "Hewlett Packard", "Adobe"
};
```

note that the ITEMS string array just is dummy data. Now here is my problem, if the user click on Apple i want to start a activity called AppleActivity. How can i with a onItemClickListener do that. In iphone sdk i can call

if (objectAtIndex == 0)

Can i do something simular? Hope you guys can help.

Jonas :)
note that the ITEMS string array just is dummy data. Now here is my problem, if the user click on Apple i want to start a activity called AppleActivity. How can i with a onItemClickListener do that. In iphone sdk i can call

if (objectAtIndex == 0)

Can i do something simular? Hope you guys can help.

Jonas :)

Comment: The answer section below is very mess. Jonas, you can add comments to the answers, instead of an answer that is in response to another one. I grabbed the code you put down there, added proper variable names, and it should work for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can , you will have something like this 
->you set adapter after

```
    yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
   //arg2 represents the position , the eletement at arg 2 that is clicked 
   if (arg2==1) startActivity (new Intent ("blabla"));
   if(arg2==2) startActivity (new Intente("Adobeeee"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because You're trying to start Adapter, while an Activity class must be a second parameter for Intent constructor. Also this activity must be described in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent algebra = new Intent(v.getContext(), AlgebraListViewController.class);
                startActivity(algebra);
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                Intent oekonomi = new Intent(v.getContext(), OekonomiListViewController.class);
                startActivity(oekonomi);
            }
        }
    });
```

This should work fine, renamed the variables so you know what they are (instead of arg0, arg1, arg2, and arg3).